# How to pass variables to the ansible provisioner in Packer?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, packer

When using vanilla Ansible playbooks, I have a number of inventories that encapsulate various configurations via the setting of variables; these work as expected. I now wish to use one or more playbooks from the Packer Ansible plugin to perform the same steps.

At present, I have resorted to passing arguments via the "--extra-vars" directive; for a limited number of variables, this is acceptable. However, I would prefer to be able to reference the existing inventory file which contains the set of variables I wish to use.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify the inventory file containing the variables in the Packer Ansible provisioner:

```
provisioner "ansible" {
  inventory_file = "${path.root}/path/to/inventory"
}
```

More information is available in the [documentation](https://www.packer.io/plugins/provisioners/ansible/ansible#inventory_file).

However, this can also become tricky since Packer normally generates an inventory file with an entry for the instance being provisioned. You may have difficulties adapting the host entry for the instance being provisioned to the existing inventory file. It may be easier to use the [inventory directory](https://www.packer.io/plugins/provisioners/ansible/ansible#inventory_directory) instead:

```
provisioner "ansible" {
  inventory_directory = "${path.root}/path/to/inventory_dir"
}
```

In that situation, Packer will still generate the guaranteed accurate inventory file for you, but `host_vars` and `group_vars` from the existing inventory files will still be available from the directory.